# How to make parsed list items open new class

Tags: android, list, parsing

I have a custom list adapter that reads in data from a xml file that is hosted online, each one is for a different article. My question is how do I make each list item open a different corresponding article? The articles will be hosted online.

Thank you in advance.

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;


public class CustomizedListView extends Fragment {  // All static variables
    // XML node keys
    static final String KEY_SONG = "song"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    static final String KEY_ARTIST = "artist";
    static final String KEY_DURATION = "duration";
    static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumb_url";

    ListView list;
    LazyAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news, container, false);



       songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


    list=(ListView)  rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);

        new RetrieveXML().execute(URL);

        // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList


        // Click event for single list row                XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {


            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }

    class RetrieveXML extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        private Exception exception;
        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();


        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {

                return parser.getXmlFromUrl(urls[0]);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                this.exception = e;
                return null;
            }
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String xml) {
            Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

            NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_SONG);
            // looping through all song nodes <song>
            for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
                map.put(KEY_ARTIST, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ARTIST));
                map.put(KEY_DURATION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DURATION));
                map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
                map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THUMB_URL));

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                songsList.add(map);

            }

            adapter=new LazyAdapter(getActivity(), songsList);

            list.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have implemented:

```
onItemClick()
```

In this you get the position of item in the list as parameter. here you can write a switch case to accomplish your task. This function gets triggered when any listitem is clicked.

Something like this you can do:

```
    private string[] mArticles={
            "abc",
            "def",
            "ghi",
            "jkl"
    };

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {

openArticle(mArticles[position]);

}
```

While creating the string array keep appropriate artile link for each item position.

Comment: but how do I make it so that each list item gets is corrresponding article?? Thanks

Comment: You can have an string array to keep the corresponding article link. Then inside onItemClick, as you know the position of list item clicked, you can call the corresponding article from your string array

Comment: happy to help. Please do accept/upvote the answer in case it solves your purpose :)

Comment: do you mind showing an example of this can be done if just gotten stuck again?

Comment: do you think there is a way to set it in the parsed xml, otherwise parsing is rendered useless? http://graffiti.hostoi.com/00Graffiti00/lists/arts.xml

Comment: Like adding the link to the article in the xml, have the onclick open a new layout with that content perhaps